How to fetch the executed pipeline details (rawlogs/output) using API call
I want to fetch the logs generated in the successful pipeline for the particular build ID using API call in plain text or text file without using any artifacts.
How can I achieve it? What are the ways we having and prerequisites for that?
I tried running the API call using PowerShell it is giving the logs of pipeline like executed time & created time, LogID all these but not the generated output .
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/logs?api-version=6.0-preview.1

This API call I have used:

Based on your requirement, you need to get the Pipeline logs in plain text or text file.
To meet your requirements, you need to get the log url first, then you can get the Pipeline log details based on the log url.
Here are two Rest APIs can meet your requirement:
Logs - List To use this Rest API, you need to add the argument: $expand=signedContent in the URL to get the valid signedContent url. We can get the pipeline step detailed log based on signedContent url.
Rest API URL:
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}/logs?$expand=signedContent&api-version=6.0-preview.1

Response sample:
  "logs": [
    {
      "createdOn": "2024-09-27T06:29:39.307Z",
      "id": 1,
      "lastChangedOn": "2024-09-27T06:29:39.45Z",
      "lineCount": 152,
      "signedContent": {
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/.....",
        "signatureExpires": "2024-09-27T07:02:09.196228Z"
      },
      "url": "xxx"
    },

PowerShell sample:
$token = "{PAT}"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelinedefinitionID}/runs/{PipelineRunID}/logs?`$expand=signedContent&api-version=6.0-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

Write-Host "$response"

foreach($log in $response.logs)
{
   $logurl =  $log.signedContent.url


   $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $logurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
   echo response1 
   echo $response1 | Out-File -FilePath {yourpath\test1.txt} -Append


  

}

TimeLine - Get This REST API can directly get the log url in the response. Then we can directly get the pipeline detailed log based on the log url.
Rest API URL
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline?api-version=6.0

Response Sample:
  {
      "previousAttempts": [],
      "id": "7f7b1dbc-43db-46ec-b65b-1c43f8d1e622",
      "parentId": "c030fdeb-f86b-5c5b-c554-cff65560abe7",
      "type": "Task",
      "name": "Initialize job",
      .....
      "log": {
        "id": 5,
        "type": "Container",
        "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_apis/build/builds/27442/logs/5"
      },
      "task": null,
      "attempt": 1,
      "identifier": null
    },

PowerShell sample:
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Orgname}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildID}/timeline?api-version=6.0"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

Write-Host "$response"

foreach($step in $response.records)
{
   $stepname =  $step.name
   $steplogurl =$step.log.url
   echo $stepname
   if($steplogurl -ne $null )
   {
     $response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $steplogurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json
     echo $response1
     echo $response1 | Out-File -FilePath {yourpath\test1.txt} -Append

   }



}


I tried all these ways i m getting the logid but  i am not able to get the content which is generated by the pipeline . we are using the microsoft Hosted agent . Can anyone please help me .

Hi Kevin,
$URL=[link APIID]version=7.1"$headers =@{Authorization = "Basic $token"}$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Headers $headers -Method Get $response $logcontent = "" foreach($log in $response.logs){$logUrl =$log.url $logResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $logUrl -Headers $headers -Method Get $logcontent += $logResponse | Out-String$logcontent} This was the script which i am running which is giving me the only upto LogId .please add the logic where i can get the pipeline output or entire log details as a string or text file.

@Mmkv Oh, I have checked your script. You are using log list rest api. In this case, you need to add $expand=signedContent in the URL and use signedContent.url to get the detailed pipeline log. The log.url will not show correct value. Please modify the script based on my first powershell sample code. This will export the expected result.

Hi Kevin,  Even after adding that also i am not getting the detailed log or expected output of the pipeline.

@Mmkv Please use this url in PowerShell: https://dev.azure.com/{orgname}/{projectname}/_apis/pipelines/{PipelinedefinitionID}/runs/{PipelineRunID}/logs?`$expand=signedContent&api-version=6.0-preview.1 And use signedContent.url

Hi Kevin, In that i want to display only the Username , LastLogin & sessionHostName  details which is generating in the output . How to achive it could you pls let me know

Are you referring to the contents in the Pipeline log? Can you share the log sample? By default, Pipeline log doesn't contain these contents. Are you doing some actions in the pipeline?

yes i am referring to the contents in the pipeline log.

yes i am referring to the contents in the pipeline log. Where in the yaml i am passing the powershell file which will give the output of  users who are not using the AVD from past 30 days. This will be givng the output as Username,Lastlogin and Sessionhostname. using the script which you have given i am able to get all the log details of the buildID. but i want to display only the userprincipalname,Lastlogin, and Sessionhostname.

Can you provide a  sample output of the Pipeline log? This will be helpful to do further research.
